# Kendo MVC: editable grid with local data

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to create editable Kendo MVC grid bound to local data(some IEnumerable<>).
I found [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud) and [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/local-data-binding). But first is only for js and second is not ediatable.

Is it possible?

I have tried all modes of Editable. But Editable() requires to specify related actions and it's impossible to prevent its execution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, editing is not supported with server side binding.  In the past, I have used a `Template` column with links to edit the items.  An example:

```
cols.Template(@<text><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new {id = item.Id})">Edit</a></text>)
```